# I need a script to send contact info from Sheets to Google Contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, contacts

My first post on Stackoverflow - NERVOUS!

I'm a Top Contributor on the Sheets forum, but I don't write code. I'm here to ask is someone would like to write this utility for me!

SHORT VERSION
I want to highlight cells in a Form Response spreadsheet and have them be sent to my Google Contacts.

LONG VERSION
I have a Google Form published on my website where the public can contact me to request my services. When a contact materializes into a client, I like to add their info to my Google Contact list so that it appears on my phone. Right now, I go to Contacts.Google.com, create a new entry, and copy paste the info.

I'm asking for a script to automate that.

I would want it to run only as needed - on demand. I don't want all Form submissions in my contact list.

My Form Response has columns for Full Name, Phone, Street Address, and Email in addition to other non-contact info.

I can reconfigure the input data in any way that you need, including isolating those items someplace else on my sheet.

What would be ultra cool is to be able to highlight the cells, execute a hotkey, and leave the house for my meeting, knowing I have my Google Contacts now has this new entry.

There's no spreadsheet to share as yet, I await your orders!

Thanks and talk soon,
Lance

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for asking someone to do work for you.  It does happen, but there is a difference between giving/receiving help and posting a need, and having someone else do the work.  I'm not trying to discourage you from posting, but try to think about how your question will be perceived by people trying to help.  If you are going to learn how to code, and want some advice on how to get started, you could post to the [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  If you aren't going to learn how to code, then Stack Overflow is not the place to post.

Comment: @Sandy Good - Ok thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you can create a Google Sheets that can be exported as a vCard format so that it can be imported by Google Contacts.